# Magento ajax add to cart result in popup box when we click on add to cart button

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have a task like; In magento, when we click on add to cart button, a popup
box has to be displayed and in that it has to display a text like
'has been added to cart' and also with two buttons like
continue shopping and proceed to checkout. So for this I have taken VS-Ajax
add to cart extension, but popup is not displaying. This everything has to
be done by Ajax functionality..

So how can I achieve this??

Answer (score -1):

[Try this](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax)

Its works for me.But in this you'll get "Alert" like product is added.

Comment: Yeah, me too receiving the same response. But I need it in the format of fancy box. I have done for product listing page. It is displaying as required, but I am unable to configure for product view page..

Comment: As I am trying to make the same thing for product view page, If I apply the same link (as I do for 'list'), it is again loading the options to this fancybox, but in the main product view page it self we have given the required options. So now I need like if I click add to cart button it has to show fancyboxx with two buttons like proceed to cart and continue shopping. For this I have created an another page like success.phtml and given the link at the add to cart buttn, nw it is loading HOME PAGE to the fancybox. I dont know how to pass it to controller or do I need to declare in .xml file???

Comment: Implementing the extension via the tutorial linked to does not provide the answer the question was asking for. No alert (success/failure) is shown in a modal/lightbox/fancybox or similar with this method although I suspect it would not take much to extend it so that it does. This would have made a better answer.